# How i create a channel Discord.JS

Tags: javascript

How i create a text channel using Discord.JS?

i've seen in other topics that the `message.guild.createChannel(....)` would create but when i use pops up an error in the console.

`(node:5564) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.guild.createChannel is not a function`

Comment: Can you share this snippet of your code? We may spot something amiss.

Comment: Sure. ```exports.run = async (client, message, args, database) => {
    let name = 'DTX'
   
    message.guild.createChannel(name, { type: 'text' })
}```

Answer (score 0):

Discord updated the method, you call channel first then specify what you want to do

```
message.guild.channels.create()
```